# Describe an O(n log n) algorithm to determine whether all of the elements of A are different

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Suppose we have two integer arrays A and B each with n elements.

Describe an O(n log n) algorithm to determine whether all of the elements of A are
different

how would u do this question? 
im quite stucked at this. i know that we have to do some sorting and this is somehow similar to binary searching. any ideas?

Comment: `"whether all of the elements of A are different"`?? Different from? B? So "whether A and B have no elements in common"?

Comment: A and B can be defined by the user itself i guess. Just have to show the working that element in A and B are different after calculating N in each of them i guess?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you sort `A` and `B`, and you get a `O(n log(n))` complexity on that part if you choose your sorting algorithm well.

Then you compare each elements of A to each element of B using the fact that both array are sorted. Here is the algorithm with `i` be the index in `[1, n]` of value of `A`, and `j` the index in `[1, n]` of values of `B`.

```
i = 1
j = 1
while i <= N and j <= N do
  if (A[i] == B[j])
    return false;
  else if (A[i] < B[j])
    i += 1
  else // A[i] > B[j]
    j += 1
end
return true;
```

This part has a O(n) complexity so the overall complexity is O(n log(n)).

Comment: Sorry to tell you but you iterate in [1,n]^2 so the complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: The complexity of iteration is O(2n) or O(n) because at each iteration you are incrementing at least one counter.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose u mean all elements of A diif from B. In this case:

Use MergeSort -to sort A (O(nlogn)
Use Merge SOrt to sort B (Onlogn)

```
private bool CheckIfEqual()     ///O(n)
{
for (int i=0;i<A.Count;i++)  //A.count=B.Count otherwise there are for sure not Equal
{
         if (a[i]!=b[i]
       return false
}
return true;
}
```

So u have O(nlogn)+O(nlogn)+O(n)=O(nlogn)

Comment: Do not work: if both A and B contains the same value x that is not in the same position in sorted A and sorted B you will miss it.

Comment: if their in other position it means their are differinet thus yo have yor answer!!

Comment: Is there any way whereby this question can be done using mathematical calculation? the only way to do this is to do through code?

Comment: @user2845853 Coding is Maths...the loop both me and Lohrun described is pseudo a function...

Comment: your objective is to prove the answer or to implement it?

Comment: in both cases , both answers give you the solution

Comment: so the answer i have to write it in a programming kind of language? i dont have to use formulas to calculate 'n' in array a and n in array b and compare them? Sorry im kinda lost on what u guys are posting, would certainly appreciate if anyone could explain to me the pseudo codes.